# The rotor does not switch in the Enigma cipher machine

Tags: python, tkinter, encryption, cryptography, enigma2

Now I am writing the Enigma cipher machine. But after writing everything, I noticed that when switching only the first rotor, it does not change the final result.

While all other rotors work perfectly

If you find the reason for the error, please write about it in the comments.

If needed, I can provide all the information on the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import string


abc = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

# rotor 3
class thirdRotor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = [(1,3),(5,20),(17,2),(2,15),(14,18),(8,1),(12,13),(18,10),(9,5),(13,24),(3,19),(23,6),(6,17),(16,12),(25,21),(15,26),(4,8),(10,25),(21,9),(26,14),(22,11),(19,16),(11,23),(24,7),(7,4),(20,22)]
        self.code_position = 0
        self.decode_position = 0

    def code(self, input, direction):
        self.code_position = self.code_position + 1
        if self.code_position > 26:
            self.code_position = self.code_position - 26
        search = self.cykleSearch((input + self.code_position))
        result = 0
        for i in range(0,26):
            if self.dictionary[i][switchDirection(direction)] == search:
                result = self.dictionary[i][direction]
        return result

    def cykleSearch(self, search):
        while search > 26:
            search = search - 26
        return search

class stator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = [(5,24),(14,19),(9,23),(26,13),(22,7),(20,12),(17,1),(21,25),(16,2),(18,3),(11,8),(10,6),(4,15),(24,5),(19,14),(23,9),(13,26),(7,22),(12,20),(1,17),(25,21),(2,16),(3,18),(8,11),(6,10),(15,4)]

    def find(self, input):
        for i in range(0,26):
            if self.dictionary[i][0] == input:
                return self.dictionary[i][1]
# rotor 2
class secondRotor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = [(18,8),(4,6),(13,5),(23,24),(12,25),(19,21),(2,14),(24,16),(3,19),(7,1),(10,23),(6,2),(20,13),(15,12),(14,10),(5,20),(17,3),(16,17),(9,22),(25,15),(11,18),(8,26),(1,7),(21,9),(22,11),(26,4)]
        self.code_position = 0

    def code(self, input, direction):
        self.code_position = self.code_position + 1
        real_position = self.code_position

        search = self.cykleSearch(input + self.cycleIterator(real_position))
        result = 0
        for i in range(0,26):
            if self.dictionary[i][switchDirection(direction)] == search:
                result = self.dictionary[i][direction]
        return result


    def cycleIterator(self, iterator):
        while iterator > 26:
            iterator = iterator // 26
        return iterator

    def cykleSearch(self, search):
        while search > 26:
            search = search - 26
        return search


# rotor 1
class firstRotor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = [(24,19),(19,20),(5,13),(6,7),(2,5),(15,25),(8,17),(9,4),(20,10),(12,11),(25,23),(11,6),(18,8),(23,2),(21,16),(16,26),(26,1),(7,21),(3,3),(4,12),(14,15),(22,9),(17,24),(13,22),(1,14),(10,18)]


    def code(self, input, direction):
        self.code_position = self.code_position + 1
        real_position = self.code_position

        search = self.cykleSearch(input + self.cycleIteratorSqrt(real_position))
        result = 0
        for i in range(0,26):
            if self.dictionary[i][switchDirection(direction)] == search:
                result = self.dictionary[i][direction]
        return result

    def cycleIteratorSqrt(self, iterator):
        if iterator // (26*26) > 1:
            while iterator > (26*26):
                iterator = iterator // (26*26)
        else:
            iterator = iterator // (26*26)
        return iterator

    def cykleSearch(self, search):
        while search > 26:
            search = search - 26
        return search


rotor_3 = thirdRotor()
rotor_2 = secondRotor()
rotor_1 = firstRotor()
stator = stator()

def crypt_word(word):
    result = list()
    for letter in word:
        result.append(codeByRotors(letter))
    return result


def codeByRotors(letter):
    number = abc.index(letter) + 1
    thirdRtl = rotor_3.code(number, 0)
    secondRtl = rotor_2.code(thirdRtl, 0)
    firstRtl = rotor_1.code(secondRtl, 0)
    statorRtl = stator.find(firstRtl)
    firstLtr = rotor_1.code(statorRtl, 1)
    secondLtr = rotor_2.code(firstLtr, 1)
    thirdLtr = rotor_3.code(secondLtr, 1)
    result = thirdLtr

    return abc[result - 1]


def switchDirection(direction):
    return 0 if direction == 1 else 1

def configureMachine(frtRrStart, sndRrStart, trdRrStart):
    rotor_1.code_position = frtRrStart
    rotor_2.code_position = sndRrStart
    rotor_3.code_position = trdRrStart


def runMachine(stringByWords):
    result = ''
    strg = ''
    for word in stringByWords:
        crypted = crypt_word(word)
        result += strg.join(crypted)
        result += ' '
    return result


def process(frtRrStart, sndRrStart, trdRrStart, inputString):
    inputString = inputString.upper()
    stringByWords = inputString.split()
    configureMachine(int(frtRrStart), int(sndRrStart), int(trdRrStart))
    result = runMachine(stringByWords)
    return result




#gui
root = Tk()
root.geometry("310x430")
root.title("Enigma")
root['bg'] = '#FF8F29'

#startentry
startentry = Entry(root, bg='#F7B237', justify=CENTER)
startentry.place(x = 10,y = 10, width=285, height=115)

#company logo
clogo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("companylogo.jpg").resize((120, 120)))
logo = Label(root, image = clogo)
logo.place(x=10, y = 150)


def Rotor_add(rotor: Label, count: int = 1):
    rotor.configure(text=rotor["text"] + count)

def Rotor_reset():
    rotor1.configure(text = 0)
    rotor2.configure(text = 0)
    rotor3.configure(text = 0)


#rotters
rotor3btn1 = Button(root, text='<', command=lambda: Rotor_add(rotor3, -1))
rotor3btn2 = Button(root, text='>', command=lambda: Rotor_add(rotor3))

rotor2btn1 = Button(root, text='<', command=lambda: Rotor_add(rotor2, -1))
rotor2btn2 = Button(root, text='>', command=lambda: Rotor_add(rotor2))

rotor1btn1 = Button(root, text='<', command=lambda: Rotor_add(rotor1, -1))
rotor1btn2 = Button(root, text='>', command=lambda: Rotor_add(rotor1))

rotor3btn1.place(x=185, y=250)
rotor3btn2.place(x=250, y=250)
rotor2btn1.place(x=185, y=210)
rotor2btn2.place(x=250, y=210)
rotor1btn1.place(x=185, y=170)
rotor1btn2.place(x=250, y=170)

#

#rotors values

rotor3 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='#FF8F29', text=0)
rotor3.place(x=220, y=250)
rotor2 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='#FF8F29', text=0)
rotor2.place(x=220, y=210)
rotor1 = Label(root, fg='black', bg='#FF8F29', text=0)
rotor1.place(x=220, y=170)

#endentry
endentry = Text(root, bg='#F7B237')
endentry.place(x = 10,y = 305, width=285, height=115)

def Enigma_Start():
    inputString = startentry.get()
    rotor1_get = rotor1['text']
    rotor2_get = rotor2['text']
    rotor3_get = rotor3['text']
    print(rotor1_get,rotor2_get,rotor3_get,inputString)
    result_all = process(rotor1_get,rotor2_get,rotor3_get, inputString)
    endentry.delete(CURRENT, END)
    endentry.insert(END ,result_all)

EncryptBtn = Button(root, text='Encrypt', command = lambda: Enigma_Start())
EncryptBtn.place(x=185, y = 135)
ResetBtn = Button(root, text='Reset', command = lambda: Rotor_reset())
ResetBtn.place(x=245, y = 135)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a bad way to write it. Polymorphism is the way to write this. There is no need for 3 different classes for the rotors.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I don't know about Polymorphism...

Comment: Well, polymorphism is an old name. Define a single class named rotor and define properties via setter ( or during construction). Many years ago, I've programmed this with only a single base class that even stator derived from it ( C++ class project). It is another permutation in the end that doesn't return. In this style, no one would look deep into your code. Quite long for this target.

Comment: oh thanks, for description